# Power Query Group By/Aggregate based on condition + dynamic columns

Tags: powerquery, m

I have a table with products (Cols E-F) from 3 countries (Col A), with weekly values (Cols H-L) and condition (Col G) based on which I need to aggregate the weekly values, and also display the aggregation logic.
Columns 44-48 are week numbers, hence these should be treated as dynamic columns.

Current table:

| Country | Producer | Packaging | Brand | SAP code | Material Description | AGG condition | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | x | x | 11111 | product 1 | sum of all 3 | 1.1 | 1.1 | 1.1 | 1.1 | 1.1 |
| 2 | x | x | x | 11111 | product 1 | sum of all 3 | 1.1 | 1.1 | 1.1 | 1.1 | 1.1 |
| 3 | x | x | x | 11111 | product 1 | sum of all 3 | 1.1 | 1.1 | 1.1 | 1.1 | 1.1 |
| 1 | y | y | y | 22222 | product 2 | sum of countries 1+2 | 2.2 | 2.2 | 2.2 | 2.2 | 2.2 |
| 2 | y | y | y | 22222 | product 2 | sum of countries 1+2 | 2.2 | 2.2 | 2.2 | 2.2 | 2.2 |
| 1 | z | z | z | 33333 | product 3 | separate | 3.3 | 3.3 | 3.3 | 3.3 | 3.3 |
| 2 | z | z | z | 33333 | product 3 | separate | 3.3 | 3.3 | 3.3 | 3.3 | 3.3 |
| 3 | z | z | z | 33333 | product 3 | separate | 3.3 | 3.3 | 3.3 | 3.3 | 3.3 |

Desired output:

[image: Expected output]

I've tried multiple options, but unfortunately can't get desired result. What would be the proper M code?

Comment: Is the AGG condition locked in or dynamic (changing each time)? Are the items fixed, or will there sometimes be 'sum of all 5' and 'sum of countries 1+2+5'

Comment: Currently there only 3 conditions: sum of all, sum of countries 1+2 and separate. I expect there can also be conditions like sum of countries 1+3 , 2+3. But not more.

One option i thought of: create separate tables by filtering based on condition -> so there are 3 separate tables -> then Append them. But perhaps that's not the best way to do this.

Comment: And what does AGG condition apply to? Just SAP code?

Comment: Basically yes, but Producer, Packaging, Brand and Material description should also remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"AGG condition", "Material Description", "SAP code", "Brand", "Packaging", "Producer", "Country"}, "Attribute", "value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"SAP code", "AGG condition", "Attribute"}, {
    {"total", each List.Sum([value]), type number}, 
    {"Producer", each _[Producer]{0}, type text },
    {"Packaging", each _[Packaging]{0}, type text },
    {"Brand", each _[Brand]{0}, type text },
    {"Material Description", each _[Material Description]{0}, type text},
    {"Alternate Country", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Distinct(_[Country]), each Text.From(_)),"+"),type text},
    {"data", each _, type table}
}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([AGG condition] <> "separate")),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"data", "AGG condition"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Alternate Country", "Country"}, {"total", "value"}}),

#"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([AGG condition] = "separate")),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows2", "data", {"Country", "value"}, {"Country", "value"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded data",{"AGG condition", "total", "Alternate Country"}),

combined = Table.Combine({#"Renamed Columns",#"Removed Columns"}),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(combined,{"SAP code", "Country", "Attribute", "value", "Producer", "Packaging", "Brand", "Material Description"}),  // needed, no idea why
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Reordered Columns", List.Distinct(#"Reordered Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "value", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: Next time please paste data and not pictures of data

Comment: Thank you, works perfect! Comment regarding data/not picture - noted!

Comment: Anyone have any idea why the #Reorder of columns needed to get the pivot to work? Never seen that before

Comment: There is a note which reads: "During the pivot columns operation, Power Query will sort the table based on the values found on the first column—at the left side of the table—in ascending order." located here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/pivot-columns which might explain it. Annoyingly, the function help page doesn't mention it at all.

Comment: Crazily enough, the #reorder doesnt change contents of the first column before the pivot, so no idea what that is. Thanks for the input though